# GDI+ memory leak from screenshot

Tags: c++, gdi+

I have a program that takes a screenshot when a specific application's window title matches the title of that window I specify. I am hooking the mouse to do this on each click in that window. The application is only open for a brief amount of time so I am ok with generating a screenshot for each click. However, when I run this program in a loop `MSG msg` for example, the application builds up .1mb each click and eventually blows up and crashes. I know this is GDI+ specific because I ruled everything else out, including the buffer I allocate globally. I am not sure that I am releasing, deleting, etc all objects/pointers, etc.

Here are global variables:

```
char *images = new char[409600];
int imageSz = 0;


void ss(HWND hwnd) // this is called from MouseProc when the wParam == WM_LBUTTONDOWN. the hwnd comes from GetForegroundWindow();
{
    using namespace Gdiplus;
    IStream* istream;
    HRESULT res = CreateStreamOnHGlobal(NULL, true, &istream);
    GdiplusStartupInput gdiplusStartupInput;
    ULONG_PTR gdiplusToken;

    RECT rWindowRect;
    GetWindowRect(hwnd, &rWindowRect);
    
    GdiplusStartup(&gdiplusToken, &gdiplusStartupInput, NULL);
    {
    // copy screen to bitmap
        HDC     hWindow = GetDC(NULL);
        HDC     hDC     = CreateCompatibleDC(hWindow);
        HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hWindow, abs(rWindowRect.left - rWindowRect.right), abs(rWindowRect.top - rWindowRect.bottom));
        HGDIOBJ old_obj = SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);
        BOOL    bRet    = BitBlt(hDC, 0, 0, rWindowRect.left - rWindowRect.right, rWindowRect.top - rWindowRect.bottom, hWindow, rWindowRect.left, rWindowRect.top, SRCCOPY);

        ULONG Bytes;
        Gdiplus::Bitmap bitmap(hBitmap, NULL);
        CLSID clsid;
        GetEncoderClsid(L"image/jpeg", &clsid);
        bitmap.Save(istream, &clsid, NULL);
        STATSTG pstatstg = {0};
        istream->Stat(&pstatstg, 0);
        int bufSz = pstatstg.cbSize.QuadPart;
        char *buffer = new char[bufSz];
        LARGE_INTEGER li;
        li.QuadPart = 0;
        istream->Seek(li, STREAM_SEEK_SET, NULL);
        istream->Read(buffer, pstatstg.cbSize.QuadPart, &Bytes);
        istream->Write(buffer, pstatstg.cbSize.QuadPart, &Bytes);

        memcpy(images+imageSz,"!!",2); // separate images with "!!"
        memcpy(images+imageSz+2,buffer,bufSz+2);
        imageSz += bufSz+2;
        delete[] buffer;

        // SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);
        // DeleteDC(hDC);
        DeleteObject(hDC);
        DeleteObject(hBitmap);
        ::ReleaseDC(NULL, hWindow);


    }
    GdiplusShutdown(gdiplusToken);
    istream->Release();
}
```

The buffer works properly otherwise so there is no leak there. In another thread, I am emptying out the buffer (but not deleting because then I cannot reallocate any memory) with:

```
   images[0] = '\0';
   imageSz = 0;
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What do the calls to `DeleteObject` return?

Comment: they both return `1`

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of mistakes in your code:

- You have `SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);` commented out, so you are leaking <sup>1</sup> the `HBITMAP` that was originally in `hDC`. `CreateCompatibleDC()` creates an `HDC` object that initially has a monochrome 1x1 `HBITMAP` selected into it. You are replacing it with your own `HBITMAP` (which is fine), but you need to restore the original `HBITMAP` before you destroy `hDC`, per the documentation for the [`SelectObject()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-selectobject) function:

  > This function returns the previously selected object of the specified type. An application should always replace a new object with the original, default object after it has finished drawing with the new object.

  <sup>1</sup> OK, maybe [not *leaking*](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100416-00/?p=14313) persay, but it is still wrong to not restore any previous GDI object you replace in an `HDC`.
- You are not un-selecting your `hBitmap` from `hDC` before giving it to the `Gdiplus::Bitmap` class.  Per the documentation for the [`Bitmap` constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/gdiplusheaders/nf-gdiplusheaders-bitmap-bitmap(hbitmap_hpalette)):

  > Do not pass to the GDI+ Bitmap::Bitmap constructor a GDI bitmap or a GDI palette that is currently (or was previously) selected into a device context.
- Your call to `istream->Write()` is completely unnecessary and should be removed.
- For that matter, you can also remove your `buffer` array completely and just `istream->Read()` directly into your `images` array instead.  Especially considering that when you are `memcpy()`'ing your `buffer` into your `images` array, you are asking `memcpy()` to copy 2 bytes more that is actually allocated for the `buffer`, which is *undefined behavior*.
- You have 2 separate threads that are sharing the `images` and `imageSz` variables, but you are not protecting the variables from concurrent access.  You MUST use a mutex or equivalent to ensure that one thread is not modifying `images`/`imageSz` while the other thread is reading from `images`/`imageSz` at the same time.

Comment: `SelectObject` must be called, although the original bitmap is [the stock one](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100416-00/?p=14313) which cannot be leaked.

Comment: @GSerg perhaps, but that is an undocumented implementation detail, not part of the contract of the API's public interface.

Comment: honestly, i copied this code from somewhere else. I don't understand how my own `HBITMAP` is being swapped in. The program needs to `HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(...)` somehow. What would the default have been? What would I need to do to swap the original back in before it is destroyed?

Comment: @unixpipe "*I don't understand how my own HBITMAP is being swapped in*" - that happens in the call to `SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);`. It is replacing `hDC`'s current bitmap with your specified `hBitmap`, and returns the previous bitmap, which is saved in `old_obj`. Later, `SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);` would swap that previous bitmap back into `hDC`.

Comment: you meaning uncommenting `SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);` ? I tried that already, believe me. It still blows up. I tried all kinds of combinations. Can you please list exactly what I need to do after I `delete[] buffer` ? Thanks

Comment: @unixpipe that problem is just ONE issue with your code, but it is not the ONLY issue. I have updated my answer.

Comment: The last 3 bullet points have been corrected. the last one did not apply as I ensured my other thread doesnt write to it, just read. The first 2 bullet points still confuse me on what I should do because even here they are doing the same thing I am: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/gdi/capturing-an-image

Comment: @unixpipe "*the last [bullet poiint] did not apply as I ensured my other thread doesnt write to it, just read*" - that is still a race condition, if it tries to read from `images` AT THE SAME TIME that `ss()` is writing to `images`. "*even here they are doing the same thing I am*" - no, because that example is not using GDI+ at all, unlike you. And one of GDI+'s requirements is that an `HBITMAP` can't be selected in a `HDC` when a `Bitmap` object is created from the `HBITMAP`. So, you need to call the 2nd `SelectObject()` *before* creating the `Bitmap` object, not *after*.

Comment: i will fix the race condition with an enumprocess in the other thread to check if that process is open and if it, it shall return. so basically, i just need to add `SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);` right after `SelectObject(hDC, hBitmap);` ?

Comment: @unixpipe No, because then the `BitBlt()` call won't fill your `hBitmap`. So, call the 2nd `SelectObject()` *after* `BitBlt()` and *before* creating the `Gdiplus::Bitmap`.

Comment: I am calling `SelectObject(hDC, old_obj);` just as you mention and still blows up eventually and crashes. it also reboots the system many times

Comment: iirc, Missing SelectObject will cause GDI handle leak but not memory leak. For OP,         `memcpy(images+imageSz+2,buffer,bufSz+2);` very likely this will overflow images as it's only 400K and can barely hold 1 or 2 images.